# How was it possible to accurately measure the mass of gases in the 19th century?

Tags: gas-laws, kinetic-theory-of-gases

I have seen periodic tables of Mendeleev (1834-1907) and Newland (1837-1898) in which masses of gases such as oxygen and nitrogen were shown. I don't think there were instruments to measure mass of gases at that time. So how were they able to predict the mass of gases at that time accurately?

Comment: Hm? Of course the molar mass of gases was known at the beginning of the 19th century. Heard of Avogadro? One liter of air weighs over one gram, that's not exactly difficult to measure.

Comment: but how were they able to know the molar mass of gases at that time?                                     And your statement "One liter of air weighs over one gram" is only telling mass of one liter of air and I can't relate that to mass of gases.

Comment: Related question on Physics Stack Exchange: [Why do gases have weight?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/280282/238167)

Answer (score 3):

There was no moles and no molar masses in the beginning of the 19th century. But gases could be weighed. If you have a vial or an ampule with a stopcock, you can make a vacuum in it (or nearly) with a water pump, and weigh it empty. Now you fill it with a given gas, and weigh it full of this gas. Then repeat the same operation with another gas. By difference, you can determine the masses of your different gases. Comparing these measurements, you will find that the gaz oxygen contained in your vial is 16 times heavier than the hydrogen, whatever the exact volume of the ampule or vial. With the same experiment, you will find that the gas we call carbon dioxide is 22 times heavier the hydrogen. All gases could be weighed and compared to the lightest of all : hydrogen. Even though the notions of atom and molecule were not accepted everywhere, all chemists could state that in the same volume, oxygen is 16 times heavier than hydrogen.